# How to use the gon gem to show database values rather than objects

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have been following [this tutorial by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast) and although it's great, the final output is a bunch of objects rather than their values.

I have a database with a model called User (name:string value:integer)

I would like the alert javascript to show me all the names and values in the database rather than just

```
 [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

My users controller is

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json

  def index
  gon.users = User.all
end
end
```

my users.js.coffee is

```
alert gon.users if gon
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `as_json` method.

```
gon.users = User.all.as_json
```

Edit:

Sorry, after checking gon seems to do it automatically.
It is just a rendering issue, so you could try:

```
var renderedUsers = JSON.stringify(gon.users);
alert(renderedUsers);
```

or in Coffee

```
renderedUsers = JSON.stringify gon.users
alert renderedUsers
```

Comment: I thought that's what gon did anyway- the documentation says it automatically creates the json without needing to convert it explicitly